# Suppose $K$ is a compact metrizable space. Then $K$ embeds homeomorphically into $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

The following fact and its proof are extracted from 'Topics in Banach Space Theory.'

> Suppose $K$ is a compact metrizable space. Then $K$ embeds
>   homeomorphically into $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Proof: Since $K$ is compact, it is separable. Let $(s_n)$ be a countable dense set in $K$. Let $\rho$ be a metric on $K$ inducing its topology. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $0 \leq \rho \leq 1.$ Define 
$$\theta:K \rightarrow [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$$ 
by $\theta(x) = (\rho(x,s_n))$. The map $\theta$ is continuous. Furthermore, $\theta$ is injective since different $x$ and $y$ will give different $n$th coordinate of $\theta(x)$ and $\theta(y)$. **Since $K$ is compact and $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is Hausdorff, $\theta$ maps $K$ homeomorphically into its image.**

Question:

$(1)$ Why $\theta$ is continuous?

It suffices to show that the map $f(x) = \rho(x,s_n)$ is continuous for each $n$. If $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}x_m=x$, then we have $|\rho(x_m,s_n) - \rho(x,s_n)| < d(x,x_m) <\varepsilon$, by triangle inequality.

$(2)$ Why can we conclude the bolded sentence?

Comment: A continuous image of a compact space is compact. Any continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta^{-1} : \theta(K) \to K$ be the inverse of $\theta$. Then $\theta^{-1}$ of $K$ is continuous if and only if $(\theta^{-1})^{-1}(F) = \theta(F)$ is closed for every closed set $F \subseteq K$. Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact. the continuous image of a compact set is compact, and compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Therefore $\theta$ and $\theta^{-1}$ are both continuous. So $\theta : K \to \theta(K)$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\theta$ is continuous: If $x\in K$ and $U$ is a nbhd of $\theta(x)$ then for some $r>0$ we have $U\supset V=\prod_nA_n$ where

(i) the set $S=\{n:A_n\ne [0,1]\}$ is finite, and (ii) $A_n=[0,1]\cap (-r+\rho(x,s_n),r+\rho(x,s_n))$ for each $n\in S.$

Now if $y\in B_{\rho}(x,r)$ then  $|\rho(y,s_n)-\rho(x,s_n)|<r$ for all $n\in S$, so $\theta (y)\in V\subset U.$